# Sort query results by time & distance columns combined or weighted

Tags: php, mysql

I'am basically trying to serve results where the persons found in my DB are the closest to you but also has been using the website recently... (job finder website...)

so I have a question similar to this
[Sort Query Results by Multiple columns using a Weight Factor to Normalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15404288/sort-query-results-by-multiple-columns-using-a-weight-factor-to-normalize)

but in my case I need to sort by Last Visit (datetime on my mySQL)
and distance (a numeric value in miles)

Based on the link above they suggest:

```
select field1, field2, field3
from stuff
order by ((popularity*0.7)*((distanceMAX-distance)*0.3)) desc
```

i'm wondering if it does apply also to datetime values like:

```
select field1, field2, field3
from stuff
order by ((datetime*0.5)*((distanceMAX-distance)*0.5)) desc
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Wondering if what also applies to datetime values?

Comment: I would suggest that you generate some examples of different distances and times and determine what ordering you want.  Pulling a formula off the web -- that you don't understand -- is unlikely to lead to useful results.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select field1, field2, field3, ((popularity*0.7)*((distanceMAX-distance)*0.3)) as temp
from stuff
order by temp desc
```